# Xcode 5 syntax coloring file type recognition of .css

Tags: xcode, text-editor

At the moment I am developing a website and I need to edit lots files of the types `.html`, `.js`, `.css` and `.pl`. My preferred text-editor is Xcode (now in Version 5.1.1) running on an iMac (OS X 10.9.3). For this tasks I am *NOT* using Xcode as an IDE. I use it just as a text editor.

In the finder I right-click the file that I want to edit and select `open with ▶︎` > `Xcode` to open it. When I do this for `.html`, `.js` and `.pl` Xcode automatically uses the correct kind of syntax coloring to highlight keywords, comments etc. in the source-code.

But when I open a `.css` file the same way then there is no highlighting automatically activated by Xcode. The complete text is written in black letters on white background. I can manually select `Editor` > `Syntax Coloring ▶︎` > `CSS` in Xcode to get the correct highlighting. But I hate to do this 50 or 100 times a day when Xcode can do this for any other file type automatically.

I want Xcode to always automatically use the CSS-highlighting when it opens a `.css` file. How can this be done?

Comment: This appears to be a bug. In Standard file types.pbfilespec, there is an entry that says:
<code>
{
        Identifier = text.css;
        BasedOn = text;
        Extensions = (css);
        MIMETypes = ("text/css");
        Language = "xcode.lang.css";
    },</code>
So it should be working properly, yet I am having the same issue.

Comment: @Alex: Where can I find this file? I can't find it using spotlight.

Comment: It is within the Xcode application package, so it is not indexed with spotlight. Available at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Standard file types.pbfilespec